# How do I create symbolic link in a VMWare shared folder that both host and guest see as a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, vmware, shared-folders

I'm using a VMWare virtual machine.  The host is Windows 8.1 with a NTFS filesystem; the guest is Linux Mint 19.  I have a VMWare *shared folder* set up, so that the guest sees part of the host's filesytem as a mountable filesystem.  It is `C:\OSPanel\domains` to the host and mounted at `/mnt/hgfs/SharedFolder/` in the guest.

How can I create a symbolic link in this shared folder that *both* host and guest see as a symbolic link?  Where the guest sees:

```
/mnt/hgfs/SharedFolder/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn → /mnt/hgfs/SharedFolder/node_modules/.bin/acorn
```

the host sees:

```
C:\OSPanel\domains\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn → C:\OSPanel\domains\node_modules\.bin\acorn
```

I have tried many ways, including `ln -s source.txt soft-link.txt`.  Nothing works.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux!  **;-)** Could you please [edit] your question and provide a bit more detailed information?  Are you trying to create a symbolic link from within the Linux VM that is readable on the host OS (Windows)?

Comment: Windows host OS, Linux guest OS. Shared folder from Windows

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** and provide much more info on your set-up:  How did you share the folder? Which File System?  Leaving a comment is  a sure-fire way of anyone but me seeing that info. *Ensure all pertinent information is in the question itself не в разделе комментариев, пожалуйста...*  **;-)**

Comment: File Systen Windows - NTFS. I tried many ways, nothing works

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also explain what the link will be pointing to. Will it be a link on the NTFS directory linking to another file/directory in the same NTFS file system? Some other NTFS filesystem? Non-NTFS filesystem?

Comment: Everything inside a shared folder(Windows, NTFS)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the tools for the filesystem in use.

In this case you need [ntfs-3G-Advanced](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/) to be able to read NTFS junctions and **need to use the Windows junction functions inside Windows** (`mklink Link Target`) as there is no tool yet (even in the advanced package) to create Windows junctions from within Linux.

**Note:** Junctions are the NTFS version of EXT symbolic links.

#### Sorry!

Comment: Maybe (big maybe) you can use PowerShell under Linux to create an LNK file, but no time to install and test right now.

Comment: i will try ntfs-3G-Advanced , thx

Comment: it needs to be installed on linux ?

Comment: Yes, but compiled from source as you're running Mint... @АлександрЧерножуков

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using the [Nemo file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager)) (which is normal for Mint), you can create symbolic links.

Select the files you want to make symbolic links to (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ select files), press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and then drag the files to the place you want to make the symbolic link.

If you get an error of some sort, [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/105381/892931) describes how to allow certain users/groups to create symbolic links.

Comment: I tried...

An error occurred when creating the symbolic link /home/alex/SharedFolder/Projects/board/tests/readme.md: Access denied


Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/ home / alex / SharedFolder / Projects / board / node_modules / acorn / bin / acorn' -> '/home/alex/SharedFolder/Projects/board/node_modules/.bin/conew